# SCALE Encode Tx Bytes using Polkadt.js SDK

Tags: polkadot-js

I'm using Polkadot.js API and I have some bytes that represent a call (similar to what you get from `tx.method.toHex()`, that don't have the encoding details embedded into it: `0x00071054657374`

I found a really rough way to get the SCALE encoded version of this call (what I would get if I do `tx.toHex()` for example) with the following approach:

```
const scaleEncodedTx = 0x + BytesLengthInHex + 04 + OriginalBytes
```

According to this, the result is `0x200400071054657374` which is correct. `BytesLengthInHex` is `20` (32 in decimal) as `0x00071054657374` has a hex-length of 16. I force the version to `04`, and then the original bytes without the `0x`.

Is there a more straightforward way using the API?

I spent some time trying to do this by creating types but could not find the proper one.

Comment: But `0x00071054657374` is a SCALE encoded Polkadot Call. So what are you trying to do with it now?  
Are you trying to encode a Transaction (Extrinsic)?